# Populating Missing Null Values with previous Non-Null Value in Presto/SQL

Tags: mysql, window, missing-data, presto, auto-populate

I have a table with multiple product , price on different date/ year. I want to fill the missing value

Data:

| Year | Product | Value |

| 2012 | A       | 100   |

| 2013 | A       | 200   |

| 2013 | B       | 150   |

| 2015 | A       | 400   |

| 2016 | B       | 500   |

Output:

| Year | Product | Value |

| 2012 | A       | 100   |

| 2013 | A       | 200   |

| 2014 | A       | 200   |

| 2015 | A       | 400   |

| 2013 | B       | 150   |

| 2014 | B       | 150   |

| 2015 | B       | 150   |

| 2016 | B       | 500   |

Query in Presto is preferred. Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Comment: 2012 B 150 missing in output

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t. year, t.product, t.value
FROM
(
SELECT CASE (WHEN a. year - LAG(a.year) >1 THEN a. year +1 ) AS   'year'  ,

CASE (WHEN a. year - LAG(a.year) >1  THEN LAG(a.product) AS 'product',

CASE (WHEN a. year - LAG(a.year) >1 THEN   LAG (a.value) AS 'value'

FROM data   a

UNION

SELECT year, product, value FROM data    ) t

ORDER BY t. year

Comment: Only read access for DB, can't use Inset and Update? Need output this  way no changes in main DB